# NSIS Script: Shortcuts of a Silent Install are not showing up

Tags: nsis, silent-installer

I got an NSIS script which starts a silent installer. In this silent installer, I create shortcuts using `CreateShortcut`. Unfortunately those shortcuts are not showing up in the Start Menu.

My workaround is to explicitly create those shortcuts but that leads to duplicated logic, which I'm not a fan of. Any ideas?

Comment: Posting some code would help...

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put the logic that creates the shortcuts? Only .onInit and Section's are executed when a installer is silent.

Could you be creating the shortcuts for the wrong user? On Vista+ if you elevate with a different user, $SMPrograms is going to resolve to their start menu...